# How do I update CLOB column on oracle with PHP

Tags: php, oracle, clob

I have problem with function:

```php
function updateClob($id_tow,$description_csv,$conn) {
    $sql = "UPDATE SHOPPER_PRODUCTS SET SHOP_TO_DESCRIPTION = EMPTY_CLOB() WHERE ID_TOW = 
            '$id_tow' RETURNING SHOP_TO_DESCRIPTION INTO :lob";
    echo $sql."\n";
    //echo $sql."\n";
    $clob = OCINewDescriptor($conn, OCI_D_LOB);
    $stmt = OCIParse($conn, $sql);
    OCIBindByName($stmt, ':lob', $clob, -1, OCI_B_CLOB);
    OCIExecute($stmt,OCI_DEFAULT);
    if($clob->save($description_csv)){
      OCICommit($conn);
      echo " Updated"."\n";
    }else{
      echo " Problems: Couldn't upload Clob.  This usually means the where 
            condition had no match \n";
    }
    $clob->free();
    OCIFreeStatement($stmt);
}
```

After execute I get "Updated" but in database column is empty. Before execute i have null on this column.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm a MySQL user & don't know anything about Oracle, so I can't really help. But wanted to say I edited your question. You had used the 'Snippets' feature on SO which is for showing & executing a working example using JS + HTML + CSS inside your post. It doesn't support any PHP. For that, you'll want to surround your code with triple backticks. & you can follow the opening triple-backticks with the programming language to help with syntax highlighting

Comment: Not familiar with oracle update syntax, seems strange that you would set it to `empty_clob()`, and then the “returning...” phrase is not something I’ve ever used. But it appears to me that your query should be `UPDATE SHOPPER_PRODUCTS SET SHOP_TO_DESCRIPTION = :clob` and the `returning` part may be optional. Then the bind would be something like `OCIBindByName($stmt, ':clob', -1, OCI_B_BLOB);`

Comment: Also, you’re using [deprecated comnands](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ocinewdescriptor.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways.  The schema is:

```sql
create table photo_tab (photo blob, photo_id number);
```

And the code would be like:

```php
// Update an existing BLOB

$photo_id = 1;
$stid = oci_parse($con, "insert into photo_tab (photo, photo_id) values(empty_blob(), :photo_id)");
$r = oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":photo_id", $photo_id);
$r = oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);
oci_commit($con);


$sql = "update photo_tab set photo = empty_blob() where photo_id = :photo_id returning photo into :photo";
$stid = oci_parse($con, $sql);
$blob = oci_new_descriptor($con, OCI_D_LOB);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":photo_id", $photo_id);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":photo", $blob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
$r = oci_execute($stid, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
$blob->savefile("/tmp/oraclelogo.jpg");
$blob->free();
oci_commit($con);
oci_free_statement($stid);

// Update an existing BLOB using a Temp BLOB

$photo_id = 2;
$stid = oci_parse($con, "insert into photo_tab (photo, photo_id) values(empty_blob(), :photo_id)");
$r = oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":photo_id", $photo_id);
$r = oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);
oci_commit($con);


$sql = "update photo_tab set photo = :photo where photo_id = :photo_id";
$stid = oci_parse($con, $sql);
$blob = oci_new_descriptor($con, OCI_D_LOB);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":photo_id", $photo_id);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":photo", $blob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
$blob->writeTemporary("/tmp/oraclelogo.jpg");
$r = oci_execute($stid, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
$blob->close();
oci_commit($con);
oci_free_statement($stid);
```

You may want to look at the second half of Oracle's free PHP book [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html).